# collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: why my view has zero subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

Please consider the following code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("DataItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DataItemCollectionViewCell

    println("\(cell.parametersView.subviews.count)")

    return cell
}
```

and the view hierarchy of the cell:

[image: view hierarchy]

I can't figure out why output is `0`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to recursively loop through all descendants of `parametersView`.

Comment: Are you sure you've set your custom class in Identity Inspector ?

Comment: Does Parameters View have a custom implementation or is it a plain old UIView?

Comment: Is `parametersView` set as `IBOutlet`? Did you  register Class in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I set up a quick project like this and didn't see any issues - are you programatically changing anything in the `DataItemCollectionViewCell` class? If so, could we see that class?

Comment: Are you sure you set the cell the identifier "DataItemCell"?

Comment: It may be good old corrupted bundle resource. Did u try clean up/delete app?

Comment: @gabbler Yes, it's set as `IBOutlet` in `DataItemCollectionViewCell` class. No.

Comment: @JohnGrant No, I don't change anything programmatically in the `DataItemCollectionViewCell` class. It's basically a class, which has a lot of `IBOutlet`s

Comment: @mengxiangjian Yes, identifier is set properly.

Comment: @orkenstein tried without any luck.

Comment: Did you set your `IBOutlet` in storyboard? Or `DataItemCollectionViewCell` has its own xib file?

Comment: Is it possible that `parameters view` in the pic is not hooked up with `IBoutlet` property, instead one of the label is?

Comment: I set `IBOutlet` in storyboard. Parameters view is hooked up properly with `IBOutlet`

Comment: The outlet to parametersView has to be set up properly since you're using Swift - if it wasn't, then when you access it to print out the count of the subviews, the app would crash when accessing nil in an implicitly unwrapped optional. Does the app crash if you try to access the `10 pax` label directly?

Comment: I've been trying to duplicate your issue without success - is there anything else you can show us that might help? (constraints / view controller / cell / the view controller scene?)

Comment: The app doesn't crash. Actually, there is nothing special with that view controller/cell

Answer (score 4):

I try to simulate a similar project and I had the same issue (my prototype cell wasn't used). Be sure that you don't have any

```swift
    self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

or

```swift
    self.collectionView.registerClass(DataItemCollectionViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DataItemCell"DataItemCollectionViewCell)
```

anywhere in your code.

Usually, there is one in the `func viewDidLoad()` function.

Edit:

Send me an exemple by mail, if you still have the problem.

Comment: No, I don't have any `registerClass` calls

Comment: You're using prototype collectioncellview I guess?

Comment: Your image and label are displayed or not?

Comment: Yes, they are displayed just fine.

Comment: Does this work: println("\(cell.contentView.subviews.count)")

Comment: @MikeTaverne it returns 0 as well

Answer (score 2):

Well I did my own collection view and tried to replicate your problem and what I noticed it's that subviews is ignoring all the `UIlabels`, but if you add, for example a UIImageView, the array subviews will have it, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412606/find-uilabel-in-uiview-in-swift) had a similar problem but the solution they provided there didn't work for me.
As a workaround you could link your labels as `IBOutlet`s to your cell prototype `DataItemCollectionViewCell`, I know it's far from clean, but if you're really desperate you can try that.
On a side note, I'm using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d), so maybe they changed something in `UILabel` in this new release.

Comment: It doesn't seem that case. I tried to add `UIImageView` to `parametersView`, but got the same result: 0 subviews

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your parameters view is being added as a subview of your cell but the `parametersView` property of the cell is not being set. Make sure your outlet is hooked up in the storyboard/xib.

I bet if you print out `cell.parametersView` you'll get nil.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not nil. I wouldn't start bounty for such simple case :)